# How to find the minimum set of vertices in a Directed Graph such that all other vertices can be reached

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Given a directed graph, I need to find the minimum set of vertices from which all other vertices can be reached.

So the result of the function should be the smallest number of vertices, from which all other vertices can be reached by following the directed edges.

The largest result possible would be if there were no edges, so all nodes would be returned.

If there are cycles in the graph, for each cycle, one node is selected. It does not matter which one, but it should be consistent if the algorithm is run again.

I am not sure that there is an existing algorithm for this? If so does it have a name? I have tried doing my research and the closest thing seems to be finding a [mother vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311614/how-to-find-mother-vertex-in-a-directed-graph-in-onm)
If it is that algorithm, could the actual algorithm be elaborated as the answer given in that link is kind of vague.

Given I have to implement this in javascript, the preference would be a .js library or javascript example code.

Comment: You meantion a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) in the title but then mention "If there are cycles in the graph..."  Do you just mean a directed graph?

Comment: No your problem is differ from that one

Comment: Sorry, yes it is just a directed graph, not a DAG, as there can be cycles. I have updated the title.

Comment: How many nodes and how many edges are we talking about?

Comment: I guess if the problem is NP complete it matters....In the application I cant imagine more than 10k nodes with about 10 edges/node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my understanding, this is just finding the strongly connected components in a graph. [Kosaraju's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm) is one of the neatest approaches to do this. It uses two depth first searches as against some later algorithms that use just one, but I like it the most for its simple concept.

Edit: Just to expand on that, the minimum set of vertices is found as was suggested in the comments to this post :
1. Find the strongly connected components of the graph - reduce each component to a single vertex.
2. The remaining graph is a DAG (or set of DAGs if there were disconnected components), the root(s) of which form the required set of vertices.

Comment: To expand on this a little:  1. Find the strongly-connected components.  2. For each one, select one of its vertices arbitrarily and contract the strongly-connected component to that vertex. This leaves a DAG.  3. Select all remaining vertices with zero in-edges. Done.  (Apologies for any errors I have introduced!)

Comment: if I look at the example graph at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component, I would want the result to be one of [a], [b] or [e]. As you can get to all other nodes (via multiple hops) from those starting nodes. But would the algorithm you've suggest produce [a,c,g]?

Comment: I should've been clearer. As Jason Orendorff suggested, you would have to find the strongly connected components (in the example - [abef],[fg] and [cdh]), reduce each to one vertex arbitrarily (say [a] [g] and [c]). Now, find the connections between these components (produces a DAG since all the cycles have been contracted to a single vertex) - this would be [ac] [cg] and choose the 'roots' (no in nodes) of the remaining graph to be your solution set.

Comment: @kyun: Good thinking, please add that comment to your answer and I'll +1.

Comment: Can you clarify the step 'Now, find the connections between these components'? Do you mean 1. use just original connections from the vertex selected or 2. find all the connections from the set of vertices in a 'component' to all other 'components'?

Comment: @Ryan Ramage  - the second thing - connections between components. You could visualize it as a second graph obtained by just reducing every strongly connected component to a single vertex.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.adj_list = [[] for _ in range(n)]

    def add_edge(self, u, v):
        self.adj_list[u].append(v)

    def find_min_ancestor_set(self):
        visited = set()
        post_order_stack = []
        for u in range(self.n):
            if u not in visited:
                self._dfs(u, visited, post_order_stack)

        visited = set()
        stack = []
        res = []
        while post_order_stack:
            u = post_order_stack.pop()
            if u not in visited:
                res.append(u)
                self._dfs(u, visited, stack)
        return res
    
    def _dfs(self, u, visited, stack):
        visited.add(u)
        for v in self.adj_list[u]:
            if v not in visited:
                self._dfs(v, visited, stack)
        stack.append(u)

def main():
    g = Graph(11)
    g.add_edge(0,1)
    g.add_edge(1,2)
    g.add_edge(2,0)
    g.add_edge(2,1)
    g.add_edge(2,4)
    g.add_edge(3,1)
    g.add_edge(5,4)
    g.add_edge(6,7)
    g.add_edge(9,10)
    g.add_edge(10,9)

    res = g.find_min_ancestor_set()
    print(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output: [9, 8, 6, 5, 3]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**[EDIT #2: As Jason Orendorff mentions in a comment, finding the feedback vertex set is overkill and will produce a vertex set larger than necessary in general.  [kyun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492831/how-to-find-the-minimum-set-of-vertices-in-a-directed-graph-such-that-all-other-v/4502418#4502418) is (or will be, when he/she adds in the important info in the comments) the right way to do it.]**

**[EDIT: I had the two steps round the wrong way...  Now we should guarantee minimality.]**

1. Call all of the vertices with in-degree zero `Z`.  No vertex in `Z` can be reached by any other vertex, so it *must* be included in the final set.
2. Using a depth-first (or breadth-first) traversal, trace out all the vertices reachable from each vertex in `Z` and delete them -- these are the vertices already "covered" by `Z`.
3. The graph now consists purely of directed cycles.  Find a [feedback vertex set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set) `F` which gives you a smallest-possible set of vertices whose removal would break every cycle in the graph.  Unfortunately as that Wikipedia link shows, this problem is NP-hard for directed graphs.
4. The set of vertices you're looking for is `Z+F`.

Comment: Why find a feedback vertex set, rather than what kyun suggests? It seems like unnecessary extra work.

Comment: @Jason: Thinking about it, you're right.  It's not necessary to find a vertex in every cycle.