# Find the smallest set of vertices from which all nodes in the graph are reachable

Tags: graph, data-science, graph-theory, vertices

This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492831/how-to-find-the-minimum-set-of-vertices-in-a-directed-graph-such-that-all-other). But how does it work with a disconnected Graph. Could someone please explain how the Kosaraju's algorithm solve the problem or maybe give another way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If the graph is disconnected, then the set of nodes from which all other nodes in the graph is reachable is empty. You could just run Kosaraju's algorithm on each connected component though.